# How does bandwidth affect a modulated digital signal?

Tags: modulation, bandwidth, digital, fsk

I'm currently reading up on how the lower layers of the ISO/OSI model work and I don't quite understand how broadband communication works yet.

Suppose I want to send some data from point A to point B on a broadband medium. I have assigned a 4kHz wide channel starting at 100kHz. Now I pass some digital data in Manchester encoding over to modem A which transmits the data to modem B. 
From my understanding, a Manchester Code signal can just be one of three values at a given point in time - thus, it would require only three different frequencies to be modulated onto.

How would changing the width of the frequency band affect the data rate I can expect? Wouldn't it just stay the same?

Comment: Read up on the Shannon Hartley channel capacity theorem: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shannon%E2%80%93Hartley_theorem.  More bandwidth means more capacity for sending data at a specified bit error rate.  Whether or not you take advantage of the extra bandwidth and do so, is another story.

Comment: Also fsk takes more spectrum than just the signaling tones in use, when switching tones to modulate data.

Comment: Manchester encoding is used in "baseband" communications. It's not really a good idea to use it with modulated signals.